# How to extract fields with exact number of occurrence of a particular character/string?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to extract rows where a character (for ex a) occurs exactly two times in a field value

For ex.

```
X   

Khaan

Amal

Ryan13

Kamala
```

The output should only contain rows with exact two (consecutive or non-consecutive) occurrences of a/A.

So sample o/p should be

```
X   

Khaan

Amal
```

I have tried

```
select * from mytable where regexp_like (X,'a{2}', 'i');
```

But it gives only one row in o/p

```
X

Khaan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the pattern `'a{2}'` is that the char `'a'` occurs 2 times consecutively.
 You can get what you need with this statement:

```
select * from mytable
where length(X) - length(replace(lower(X),'a', '')) = 2
```

It operates case insensitively.
It removes all occurrences of `a` and subtracts the length of the remaining string from the length of the initial string. If the result is 2 then the string is returned.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a2cbc8710ac41a313a56193a28830137).
Results:

```
> | X     |
> | :---- |
> | Khaan |
> | Amal  |
```

Edit.
For a string like 'abc', use this:

```
select * from mytable
where length(X) - length(replace(lower(X),'abc', '')) = 2 * length('abc')
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need to wrap the second `length` within `nvl(......, 0)`. If the string is made *entirely* of a and/or A, the result of `replace` is `null`, and then so is the `length`. This means that `AAA` will not pass the filter, but neither will `AA`, and you do want to catch the latter as meeting the requirement. I'll edit your answer to add the `nvl`.

Comment: This solution works. What if string needs to be matched instead of single character ? Multiple occurrences that is.
And thanks for introducing to dbfiddle!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, use `REGEXP_COUNT`:

```
SQL> with test (x) as
  2    (select 'Khaan'  from dual union all
  3     select 'Amal'   from dual union all
  4     select 'Ryan13' from dual union all
  5     select 'Kamala' from dual
  6    )
  7  select x
  8  from test
  9  where regexp_count(x, 'a', 1, 'i') = 2;

X
------
Khaan
Amal

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for this:

```
where lower(x) like '%a%a%' and
      lower(x) not like '%a%a%a%'
```

With regular expressions, one method is:

```
where regexp_like(x, '^[^aA]*[aA][^aA]*[aA][^aA]*$')
```